# git push via cron + ssh-agent (no password)

Tags: git, bash, ssh, cron

Since this has already come up, just want to get the related posts out of the way:

Permission denied (publickey); not my issue:

- [git push via cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994663/git-push-via-cron)
- [cron git push with ssh key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852577/cron-git-push-with-ssh-key)

The closest and what got me where I am, but not working for me:

- [cron git push with ssh key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852577/cron-git-push-with-ssh-key#)

There's no indication on the last one of *what*, exactly, led the top answer to be marked solved but I'm having no issues with the suggested troubleshooting script or manual password-less/ssh-agent-based pushes to github.

I have a python file that writes to a log, which I'd like pushed to github every minute automatically from my raspberry pi. Here's the script:

```
~/dir/script
export HOME=/home/uname
cd /home/uname/dir/
echo $HOME
pwd
whoami
python2 ./python-script.py
git commit -am "update"
git push
```

When I run it manually, I get the following output:

```
$ ./script 
/home/uname
/home/uname/dir
uname
done ### print from script
[master 0db9599] update
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 306 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To uname@github.com:uname/repo.git
   def0bed..0db9599  master -> master
```

So, all looks great!

Here's the crontab line (edited via `crontab -e` as my regular user):

```
*/1 * * * * /home/uname/dir/script
```

Here's my `journalctl` log after `cron` runs:

```
CROND[13791]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user uname
crond[13862]: pam_unix(crond:session): session opened for user uname by (uid=0)
CROND[13863]: (uname) CMD (/home/uname/dir/script)
CROND[13862]: (uname) CMDOUT (/home/uname)
CROND[13862]: (uname) CMDOUT (/home/uname/dir
CROND[13862]: (uname) CMDOUT (uname)
CROND[13862]: (uname) CMDOUT (done)
CROND[13862]: (uname) CMDOUT ([master 4fd590d] update)
CROND[13862]: (uname) CMDOUT ( 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-))
CROND[13862]: [50B blob data]
CROND[13862]: (uname) CMDOUT (fatal: Could not read from remote repository.)
CROND[13862]: (uname) CMDOUT ()
CROND[13862]: (uname) CMDOUT (Please make sure you have the correct access rights)
CROND[13862]: (uname) CMDOUT (and the repository exists.)
CROND[13862]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user uname
```

From googling around a bit to make sure the user was properly set for github, I tried the explicit command shown in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551409/how-to-change-git-ssh-user-for-a-remote-push-temporarily):

```
git push ssh://uname@github.com/uname/repo.git
```

I'm no git expert, so I thought this was just an example on github
but it appears to work fine, too:

```
git push ssh://git@github.com/uname/repo.git
```

I also tried the `~/.ssh/config` suggestion from the [same answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852577/cron-git-push-with-ssh-key#). Namely:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host github-project1
User git
HostName github.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Then:

```
git remote add github-project1 github-project1:uname/repo.git
```

I get the same results with all variants I've tried; manual pushes and the script execute fine but `cron` fails.

What further can I check?

Comment: `ssh -vvv git@github.com verify` should tell you more.

Comment: @Jakuje I can post a full log if you'd like, but 2/3 down I get `debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey)` and it exits with `debug1: Exit status 1`. Should I re-do that from the script/cron and save the log to compare?

Comment: Also when you run it from cron?

Comment: @Jakuje they're definitely different, and in the process of googling what I think was the problem, I've solved the issue. The cron-executed script log features `read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address` and then fails. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499680/why-does-this-bash-script-work-at-console-but-fails-when-run-as-a-cron-job) says it's because `ssh-agent` isn't accessible to `cron` since it runs outside of a sesson. Thanks for the tip; should have thought of doing that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> git push via cron + ssh-agent (no password)

Cron usually does not have access to your `ssh-agent`, because there is environment variable `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in your shell, but it is probably not in the one that is used by `cron`.

Comment: And I don't suppose I could set it in my script with `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/blahblah`, right?

Comment: You can, but then you will depend on. Some other running session providing this socket and the pass phrase earlier.